# Why does Puss in Boots have a new girlfriend "Dulcinea" in the 2015 TV show?

Tags: shrek, puss-in-boots

Why does Puss in Boots have a different girlfriend in [*The Adventures of Puss in Boots*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3807034/) TV series compared to [the *Puss in Boots* movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puss_in_Boots_(2011_film))?

He's seeing **Dulcinea** in the TV series

[image: smiling blue-eyed white cat, wearing a wihte and blue dress, holding a basket]

And **Kitty Softpaws** in the movie.

[image: Black and white cat wearing boots and a belt]

Do we know what happened to her?

Comment: Really? You're asking why a swashbuckling cat has more than one girlfriend??  Because he's a cat... And a swashbuckler.  :)

Comment: @Paul - Tomcats are not exactly renowned for their monogamous ways.

Comment: @valorum. Precisely. I think there's even a term "catting around" in some places.

Comment: Because he goes tilting at windmills? Does he have a sidekick who rides a donkey? Seriously, the writers are shameless.

Comment: Whats more scandalous is: why is Kitty Softpaws posing naked?!?!??!

Answer (score 9):

The TV series is set *before* the 2011 movie in which he meets Kitty for the first time.

> I wanted to set the show earlier in Puss's life, back when he was the only one who thought he was a legend. When he had more to prove, and maybe wasn't quite so awesome at everything yet. **So the series is set before the Puss In Boots movie, which in turn is set before the Shrek movies.**
>
> The Puss In Boots movie has a lot of spaghetti western elements, and we leaned further in that direction. We didn't want to go full fairytale, because the Shrek franchise really has that arena pretty well sewn up. **Also, the Shrek movies have already used practically every well-known fairytale character there is, and since our series is set before those movies we couldn't use any of those characters. So it felt like we needed to go somewhere else.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Netflix's 'Puss In Boots' Series Creator On Secrets, Surprises & Why You Have To Watch](https://www.techtimes.com/articles/27047/20150116/interview-netflix-puss-boots-series-creator.htm)</sup></sub>

As to what happened to *Dulcinea*, the fate of his relationship with her wasn't confirmed in the show (and was left open, presumably in expectation that Netflix would pay for a seventh season). All we know is that by the time he meets Shrek, he's single again. Presumably they broke up.

Comment: And he never even met Dick Whittington.

Comment: @Spencer - I expect they're saving that for the sequel